# How do I remove this connector from a solid electrical wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, junction-box, connectors

I'm trying to replace the light above my kitchen table. The junction box seems to have a solid electrical wire. It was connected to the light's stranded wire with this connector here and also wrapped in what looked like sticky black rubber. I peeled off as much of the rubber as possible and then I cut the stranded electrical wire to remove the old light. I tried to pry the connector open by the stranded wires and it looks like it could be gold inside? How do I remove the solid junction box electrical wire from this connector now?

I need to connect the solid wire to my new light fixture which also has a stranded electrical wire. My new light fixture includes the simple plastic wire twist connectors which I know how to use. [image][image]

Comment: Sticky black rubber sounds like electrical tape.  Most connectors are of the screw type.  You screw them on, you screw them off.  Can also in most cases just cut the wire near them and strip the wire and put new connector on.

Comment: Hi @crip659. I was finally able to include some pictures. These look like crimp connectors possibly and not the screw ones? The original light is probably at least 20 years old (previous owner had it installed). Am I able to cut a solid wire? I thought I could only cut stranded wires. Thanks.

Comment: Can cut solid as easy as stranded, find solid easier to cut since you don't miss cutting the fine strands.  They are crimp connectors and cutting is only way.  Strip the insulation back from cut(about 1/2 inch) and use wire nuts.

Comment: Thank you!! Simple enough!

Answer (score 12):

These don't get "removed", they get cut off. Snip the copper solid wire at the end of those connectors, strip off the insulation and then use wire nuts or some other approved connector to connect the wires for your new light.

Comment: Yep, let's not over think this, great answer!  +

Comment: Thanks! I should have posted here from the get go. I seriously thought solid wires couldn't be cut because of something I read on the internet. You wouldn't believe how much time I wasted. Lol.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I added the "or some other approved connector" because I've never seen crimped connections like that for a light and thought it might be in a different country, one that doesn't allow wire nuts......  I'm finally thinking globally... lol  stay safe.